# Xamarin Forms shared project new content page cs file not coupled

Tags: xamarin.forms

Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

Xamarin Cross Platform App, Blank App, Xamarin.Forms, Shared Project.

Within the shared project, if I add a new Xamarin.Forms Content Page (Page1), the .xaml and xaml.cs files are not coupled like you would expect.

[image]

I found a work around by manually editing the .projitems file as you'd expect to (replacing the SubType tag with the DependentUpon tag):

```
>     <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MainPage.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Page1.xaml.cs">
        <SubType>Code</SubType>
      </Compile>
```

Seems this is a bug?  Anyway to not have to do this manual edit to get the desire result?

Comment: I have had this happen to me before.  I usually delete the pages and restart VS and it seems to work so it does appear to be a repeating bug.

Comment: Sounds like you're running into [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55901) bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what could be wrong here. As you pointed out you could choose to edit the project file.

Another solution which does not require you to edit the project file manually is:

1. Exclude both `.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` from your project (Right click files => exclude from project)
2. Select Add existing item (Right click project => Add existing item)
3. Select the `.xaml` file only

Visual studio should now import both files and 'couple' them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using VS2017 15.6.2 and besides the bug you mention, in my case the .xaml file is not included in the project!!.

My Solution, make sure to have this two sections in your .projitems file

1st: To display the .xaml.cs file as a child within the .xaml file

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Page1.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>Page1.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

2nd: To include the file in your project

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Page1.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

greetings from Chile!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in VS 2019 for Mac.
I resolved the issue by

1. Select add a new file
2. Write the same name.
3. VS found the file and added it to the project as expected connections